# Is there any way for me to get a whole tree with one query while only knowing the parent id?

Tags: mysql, tree

I am looking for a non-recursive solution to make a MySQL query to select all of the leaf nodes (children, grandchildren etc) of a node while only knowing who the direct child of the node is.

Currently I have the following tables:

> Nodes:
>
> - id (INT)
> - data (VARCHAR)
>
> Relationships:
>
> - parentId (INT)
> - childId (INT)
> - childNodeOrder (INT)

The way I have it currently I can only select the **direct** child nodes of a parent node (for this example let the parent Id = 1):

```
SELECT * FROM  Nodes n
JOIN Relationships r ON r.childId = n.id
WHERE r.parentId = 1
ORDER BY r.childNodeOrder;
```

Is there any way for me to change this database around easily to **not** use a recursive call (on my server side code) and to be able to get all of the descendant leaves of a parent?

I so far have looked at questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252323/mysql-closure-table-hierarchical-database-how-to-pull-information-out-in-the-c) which would seem like a radical change, and not very easy to switch over...

Comment: Why are you only storing direct relationships in the table?

Comment: @Esailija that is my question, what and how can I change my database to be more useful for what I need to do...?

Comment: So the question is that you understand your table is screwed and need to know how to convert it to the proper closure table format?

Comment: @Esailija yes. that is what my question is... :-\

Comment: It is pretty bad DB relation design, exactly because of difficulties with performing typical tree operations on your data. Probably easiest way to implement non-recursive search in hierarchical structure is to add "path" column to your table.

Comment: @samuil Actually closure table is the best solution for that afaik, he just implemented it wrong

Comment: Generally there are multiple options. I like this overview: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database . Everything depends on what are most common operations that will be performed on the set.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient/elegant way to parse a flat table into a tree?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree)

Answer (score 1):

See the NESTED SET data model, it probably can help here.

http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Edit: since more context is needed, here are the details.

A parent node will have a left and right attributes that cover a range [left, right].

All the children nodes will be included in that range, so that:

parent.left <= child.left <= child.right <= parent.right.

All leaf nodes have a range of 1, so that left + 1 = right only for leaves.

To get all the leaves from a parent, use a where clause similar to this:

WHERE (left + 1 = right) AND (left >= parent.left) AND (right <= parent.right)

Comment: Answers that are links are **not** answers. Please add some context.... The way your answer is now, it is more of a _comment_.

Comment: just sayin' the provided link in this case is actually pretty darn useful :)