# mysql query to indent child and group all childs

Tags: php, mysql, parent-child, hierarchical-data, adjacency-list

I have a mysql table like this

```
id  Category         parent
2   Garments           12
3   Gents Garments          2
4   Sarees                  2
5   Bridal Sarees           4
6   IT                 12
7   IT Hardware         6
8   IT Software         6
9   Web Design          8
10  Web Based Solution  8
11  E-Commerce Solution 9
12  root                 NULL
```

Using the mysql query

```
SELECT t1.category AS lev1, t2.category as lev2, t3.category as lev3, 
t4.category as lev4
FROM categories AS t1
LEFT JOIN categories AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.id
LEFT JOIN categories AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.id
LEFT JOIN categories AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.id
WHERE t1.category = 'root';
```

I am able to get this result

```
lev1    lev2       lev3            lev4
root    Garments  Gents Garments   NULL
root    Garments  Sarees       Bridal Sarees
root    IT    IT Hardware      NULL
root    IT    IT Software      Web Design
root    IT    IT Software      Web Based Solution
```

Now I couldn't find a way of getting the values in a single column in a tree like structure.
example

```
root
--Garments
----Gents Garments
----Sarees
--IT
----IT Hardware
----IT Software
------Web Design
------Web Based Solution
```

**Question modified using following query:**

I have partly achieved the above result but steel needs proper grouping using 
following query

```
SELECT distinct t1.category AS category
FROM categories AS t1
LEFT JOIN categories AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.id
LEFT JOIN categories AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.id
LEFT JOIN categories AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.id
WHERE t1.category = 'root' 
union
SELECT distinct concat('--', t2.category) as category
FROM categories AS t1
LEFT JOIN categories AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.id
LEFT JOIN categories AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.id
LEFT JOIN categories AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.id
WHERE t1.category = 'root'  
union

SELECT distinct  concat('----', t3.category) as category
FROM categories AS t1
LEFT JOIN categories AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.id
LEFT JOIN categories AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.id
LEFT JOIN categories AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.id
WHERE t1.category = 'root' 
union
SELECT distinct concat('------', t4.category) as category
FROM categories AS t1
LEFT JOIN categories AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.id
LEFT JOIN categories AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.id
LEFT JOIN categories AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.id
WHERE t1.category = 'root'
```

Result I am getting is 
root
--Garments
--IT
----Gents Garments
----Sarees
----IT Hardware
----IT Software
------Bridal Sarees
------Web Design
------Web Based Solution
But I want the result like
root
--Garments
----Gents Garments
----Sarees
------Bridal Sarees
--IT
----IT Hardware
----IT Software
------Web Design
------Web Based Solution

Comment: That's something you should handle in your presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

If you could change the way you represent the hierarchy to a transitive closure table, you could take advantage of a couple of past answers I have given. The topic was how to control sorting of the output of the query, in the same way you describe above.

- [MySQL Closure Table hierarchical database - How to pull information out in the correct order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252323/mysql-closure-table-hierarchical-database-how-to-pull-information-out-in-the-c/8288201#8288201)
- [Sorting a subtree in a closure table hierarchical-data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069674/sorting-a-subtree-in-a-closure-table-hierarchical-data-structure/14074310#14074310)