# Need explanation on this SQL Closure Table Query

Tags: mysql, sql, transitive-closure-table

As a response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252323/mysql-closure-table-hierarchical-database-how-to-pull-information-out-in-the-c), Bill Karwin posted the following query to pull back an ordered sub-tree given any particular tree-node-id:

```
SELECT d.`iD`, d.`subsectionOf`,
   CONCAT(REPEAT('-', p.`len`), d.`name`) as hier,
   p.`len`, p.`ancestor`, p.`descendant`,
   GROUP_CONCAT(crumbs.`ancestor`) AS breadcrumbs
       FROM `TreeData` AS d
       JOIN `TreePaths` AS p ON d.`iD` = p.`descendant`
       JOIN `TreePaths` AS crumbs ON crumbs.`descendant` = p.`descendant`
       WHERE p.`ancestor` = 1
       GROUP BY d.`iD`
       ORDER BY breadcrumbs;
```

I myself have successfully used this query in a couple of my own projects, but I realized that I don't understand exactly how and why this query works.  I feel I have a decent understanding of the closure table design (primarily through reading Karwin's deck on SQL handling hierarchical data).  Nonetheless, I am not comfortable that I can "finger trace" this query and explain how it is constructing the result set.

Specifically, I am having the most trouble understanding the second JOIN on the "treePaths" table (which I understand to be the actual closure table that records the ancestor and descendent relationships for each node/leaf).  How does this create the breadcrumbs result?